# How robust is discrete logarithm in $GF(2^n)$?

Tags: number-theory, discrete-logarithm, finite-field

"Normal" discrete logarithm based cryptosystems (DSA, Diffie-Hellman, ElGamal) work in the finite field of integers modulo a big prime $p$. However, there exist other finite fields out there, in particular binary fields $GF(2^n)$. There is a specific attack described by Coppersmith for discrete logarithm in a binary field, and it was later on refined into the more general [Function Field Sieve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_field_sieve) by Adleman and Huang. The FFS was used by Joux and Lercier to obtain the [current record in $GF(2^n)$ discrete logarithm](https://listserv.nodak.edu/cgi-bin/wa.exe?A2=ind0509&L=NMBRTHRY&P=R1490&D=0&I=-3&T=0), where $n = 613$.

What I would like to know is:

- How does discrete logarithm in $GF(2^n)$ compares to discrete logarithm modulo a prime $p$ of $n$ bits ? At the time when Coppersmith published his algorithm, it made discrete logarithm in binary fields look easier than its prime $p$ counterpart, but the latter also got improved later on.
- Is it important, for discrete logarithm in $GF(2^n)$, whether $n$ is itself prime or not ? The current record is for $GF(2^{613})$, beating the previous record of $GF(2^{607})$, and both 607 and 613 are prime numbers. Would discrete logarithm in $GF(2^{1024})$ be easier than in $GF(2^{1021})$ ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[Discrete logarithms in $\mathbb{F}_{p}$](http://library.msri.org/books/Book44/files/12oliver.pdf)  share the same asymptotic complexity as integer factorization for general numbers: $L_p[1/3,1.923]$ for general integers, $L_p[1/3,1.587]$ for [special integers](https://eprint.iacr.org/2006/107). [Discrete logarithms in $\mathbb{F}_{p^n}$](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=305385) have the same asymptotic complexity as factoring special integers, i.e. $L_{p^n}[1/3, 1.587]$, via the Function Field Sieve.

So, extrapolating from the factoring records, we can handwave that a discrete log in $\mathbb{F}_{2^{1021}}$ is an order of magnitude easier than a discrete log modulo a 768-bit general prime, and about the same as modulo a pseudo-Mersenne prime $2^{1021} - c$.

As to whether composite degree extension fields are easier to solve, maybe. It is possible to represent the same composite field in a number of ways (usually known as tower of fields), and it is possible that some representations allow for faster breaks than others. Here's a quote from Andrew Odlyzko's 1985 paper [Discrete logarithms and their cryptographic significance](http://www.dtc.umn.edu/%7Eodlyzko/doc/arch/discrete.logs.pdf):

> In fact, these ﬁelds may be very weak because of the possibility of moving between the ﬁeld and its subﬁelds.

However, there is [no data on significant asymptotic advantages](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-540-40974-8_16?from=SL) of composite degree over prime degree (if there was, pairing-based schemes would be toast, as embedding degrees are by and large composite).

One shouldn't also forget to check the smoothness of $p^n-1$, to avoid embarrassing Pohlig-Hellman breaks.

### May 2013 Update

It seems that composite degree is indeed weaker than prime degree. The recent results of [Göloğlu et al](https://eprint.iacr.org/2013/306) and [Joux](https://eprint.iacr.org/2013/095) attack fields $\mathbb{F}_{2^n}$, for composite $n$, much faster than the function field sieve referred above. See [this question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/8479/do-recent-announcements-about-solving-the-dlp-in-gf26120-apply-to-schemes/8506) for more information.

Comment: Welcome to Crypto Stack Exchange! Sadly, [we don't yet have MatJax Formula support enabled here](http://meta.crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/8/do-we-need-mathjax), so your formulas look a bit raw. Also, your links are somehow missing.

Comment: Alright, removed the LaTeX syntax, and did some general fixing (including links).

Comment: As we now have working LaTeX syntax, I added the formulas again to your post. Please check that I didn't transform anything wrong.

Comment: There has been recent results that seem relevant to the question, including Göloğlu, Granger, McGuire, and Zumbrägel's [Solving a $6120$-bit DLP on a Desktop Computer](https://eprint.iacr.org/2013/306)

Comment: Highly composite extension degree means that the order of the multiplicative group will automatically have some factors. This in turn allows Chinese remainder theorem based attacks on DLP. However, a single large prime factor will still spell trouble for the attacker. For example 2^1024-1=(2^512-1)(2^512+1). The latter factor is a Fermat number [F_9 with a known factorization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat_number) and its largest factor is about 7*10^92. Still very large, but some of the size will get wasted when you have automatic factors. Mersenne primes are good in this respect.

Comment: @SamuelNeves it looks like you might have two accounts. You can [merge them](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts).

Answer (score 8):

Antoine Joux very kindly sent me the following on the topic:

> People worry that [logarithms over fields with composite exponent] might be easier,
>   this is why they use prime exponent. For some factorization of the exponent, viewing
>   the finite field as a tower of extensions $(p^{n_1})^{n_2}$ indeed makes things easier.
>
> See "[The function field sieve in the Medium Prime Case](http://www.iacr.org/cryptodb/data/paper.php?pubkey=2435)" by R. Lercier and myself.

---

<sup>*[The portion below, while correct, is not relevant to this question. I have not deleted it as that would leave the comment dangling.]*</sup>
Elliptic cuves over $GF(2^m)$ where $m$ is composite are potentially vulnerable to attacks based on Weil descent. People wishing to show the state of the art in discrete logarithm computation choose problems with m a prime so that no such shortcuts are possible.

The paper [Analysis of the GHS Weil Descent Attack on the ECDLP over Characteristic Two Finite Fields of Composite Degree](http://eprint.iacr.org/2001/084) (2001) by Markus Maurer, Alfred Menezes and Edlyn Teske is the most recent work on the topic I can conveniently find.

Comment: Note that the Weil descent approach to elliptic curves of composite-degree transfers the discrete logarithm from $E(\mathbb{F}_{2^n})$ to $J(\mathbb{F}_{2^{(n/p)}})$, where $p$ is some divisor of $n$, and $J$ is the Jacobian of a high-degree hyperelliptic curve where the discrete log might be faster.


The original question, however, was about discrete logarithms in the base field $\mathbb{F}_{2^n}$; the Weil/Tate pairing might be used to transfer $E(\mathbb{F}_{2^n})$ to $\mathbb{F}_{2^n}$ (MOV and FR attacks).

Answer (score 4):

To complete @Samuel's answer, there are a few shortcuts that can be used when $n$ is composite; however, they only contribute small constant factors, hence they do not change the asymptotic behavior:

- If $n$ can be divided by $r$, then one can first solve the discrete logarithm in the subfield $GF(2^r)$. In a sieve-based algorithm, this can provide up to half the relations that we need for the final linear algebra step.
- The final linear algebra step of the FFS computes things modulo $2^n-1$. If $n$ is not prime, then $2^n-1$ is not prime either, and such operations can be implemented more efficiently through the use of the [Chinese Remainder Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem).

Also, if working in a subgroup, one can botch the choice of the subgroup. If $n = rs$ for non-trivial factors $r$ and $s$, then $GF(2^n)^{*}$ has size $2^n-1$, which is a multiple of $2^r-1$. If we choose a subgroup generated by a value $g$ of order $q$ where $q$ divides $2^r-1$, then we are actually computing things in $GF(2^r)$ and we can solve the discrete log by working in that subfield, where attacks are much more efficient, since $r$ is no more than $n/2$. In other words, when choosing the subgroup order $q$ (a prime), we must make sure that $q$ does not divide any $2^r-1$ for any $r$ which divides $n$. A prime $n$ is a simple way to ensure that.